# WAR created using Clojure deployed on Apache Tomcat does not run Servlet

Tags: tomcat, clojure, compojure

I created the sample WAR as given at the Compojure [Getting Started Page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Compojure/Getting_Started#Hello_World_in_a_War_file) and deployed it to Apache Tomcat 6.0.2 wepapps folder. The Web.xml I used is as below:

```
<web-app>
 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>myapp.MyServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Accessing the URL throws the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Handler returned nil (maybe no routes matched URI)
    compojure.http.servlet$request_handler__72.invoke(servlet.clj:110)
    myapp.MyServlet$_service__108.invoke(MyServlet.clj:11)
    myapp.MyServlet.service(Unknown Source)
```

I have included the Clojure, Clojure contrib jars in the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Has anyone encountered similar issue with Clojure WARs on Apache Tomcat ?

The Servlet I am trying to run is :

```
 ;; src/myapp/MyServlet.clj
(ns myapp.MyServlet
    (:use compojure)
    (:gen-class
        :extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet))

(defroutes greeter
    (GET "/"
        (html [:h1 "Hello World"])))

(defservice greeter)
```

When I replaced the `(defservice greeter)` with

```
(run-server {:port 8080}
  "/*" (servlet greeter))
```

I am able to run this and access URL from browser.

However, when I run this from Apache Tomcat, I still face the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem happened to be related to the use of `"/"` in the defroutes instead of `"/*"`. If I define the defroutes as :

```
(defroutes greeter
    (GET "/*"
        (html [:h1 "Hello World"])))
```

It works on Apache Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 5):

1) Did you actually define routes? Sounds like an obvious place to start. Make sure your routing table exists and is correctly defined. You need something like:

```
(defroutes webservice
  (GET "/some-route/"
    some-function-name))) ;; more complicated variations are possible, of course
```

2) Try starting your app in Jetty. If it doesn't work under Jetty either, with the same error, then your problem is not in the WAR deployment but in the app.

```
(defserver webserver
             {:port 8080}
             "/*" (servlet webservice))
(start main-server) ;; starts a Jetty webserver on 8080
```

If neither of these fixes it, post some more information for us, such as your routing table.

Comment: I added the following to test my Servlet and this runs fine.

(run-server {:port 8090}
 "/*" (servlet greeter))